# Get data from dynamically added elements and pass to Django request.POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, django-views

I have a restaurant_form which allows user to input menu items. Each menu item represent a table row which is added dynamically. Each table row has input for: menu item, price, halal(Boolean), and notes.

Here is a sample entry. data-ids and names of input elements are incremented.

```
<tbody class="menu-entry ">
    <tr id='menu0' data-id="0" class="hidden">
        <td data-name="name" class="name">
            <input type="text" name='name0'  placeholder='Menu Item' class="form-control"/>
        </td>
        <td data-name="price">
            <input type="text" name='price0' placeholder='0.00' class="form-control"/>
        </td>
        <td data-name="halal">
            <input type="checkbox" name="veg0" value="halal" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td data-name="notes">
            <textarea name="notes0" placeholder="Contains soy." class="form-control"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td data-name="del">
            <button name="del0" class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove'></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What is the best way to retrieve data from the table? I have tried this:

```
  $('#restaurant_form').submit(function () {
        $('.menu-entry').each(function()
        {
            $(this).find('td').each(function(){
                $(this).find("input").each(function() {
                    alert(this.value)
                });

                $(this).find("textarea").each(function() {
                    alert(this.value)
                });
            })
        })
  })
```

The alert() shows the correct values however I am wondering if there is a better way to do this?

**Edit** I simplified it using:

```
$('.menu-entry .form-control').each()
```

Also, after retrieving the values, how can I pass it to the view with a POST request? I would like to save the values to model 
RestaurantMenu with columns name, price, halal and notes.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to use $("menu-entry .form-control").each()

Comment: @SergAnuke thanks for the tip! $('.menu-entry .form-control').each() works :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

For every menu entry, I converted the values to a string separated by comma and added a hidden input to hold the value. I added class 'menu-row' to tr.

```
$('#restaurant_form').submit(function () {

      $('.menu-row').each(function(){
          var menu_entry = ""

          $(this).find('.form-control').each(function(){
              menu_entry = menu_entry + this.value + ","
          })

          $('#restaurant_form').append('<input type="hidden" name="menu_entries" value="'+ menu_entry +'" />')
          alert(menu_entry)

      })
  })
```

In views.py :

```
menu_entries = request.POST.getlist('menu_entries')
        for menu_entry in menu_entries:
            entry = menu_entry.split(",")
            if entry[1]:
                price = round(float(entry[1]), 2)
            else:
                price = 0.00
            if not entry[2]:
                entry[2] = False
            MenuItems.objects.create(name=entry[0], price=price, halal=entry[2], notes=entry[3], restaurant_id=r.id)
```

If anyone knows a better approach, I would love to know. Thank you!